# Why did Mirabel not receive a gift?

Tags: encanto

As of the beginning of *Encanto*, Mirabel is the only person born into the Madrigal family not to have received a gift, with people receiving gifts both before and after her. The manner in which she did not receive her gift was intriguing, too: a door *started* to form for her, then disappeared. Even more intriguingly,

> at the end of the film, she opens the front door, which turns magical and forms an image of the family with her front and center. If a door means a gift, this may imply that she did eventually receive a gift of some sort.

Some have pointed to the magic being connected to family ties as an explanation. However, Mirabel only began to not be accepted *after* not receiving a gift, for precisely that reason. Similarly, one might imagine that her grandmother's fear due to Bruno's prophecy impeded the process; but then, she was visibly more worried that Antonio would not receive a gift, and everything went well.

Why did Mirabel, among all the family, not receive a gift?

Comment: All of the children get a gift in line with their personality. Alas, Mirabel is "steadfast and steady" and basically has no personality.

Comment: @Valorum - I don't know about that. Compared to the other family members, she showed herself to be compassionate and unwilling to stand for injustice (we saw how she vowed to get Bruno out of the walls and called her grandmother out for holding the family to impossible standards, but also was able to see her grandmother's sacrifices), courageous (almost no one else took any risks, whereas she risked her life both to go into Bruno's cave and to save the candle), irritable (she loses her temper more than the rest of the family) and perceptive (she figured a lot of things out, after all).

Comment: She did receive a gift, and an absolutely crucial one at that. Mirabel is like the conductor of an orchestra.  The conductor's baton is considered a musical instrument even though it makes no sound.

Answer (score 9):

We never saw what happened when the others received their gifts, just Mirabel and Antonio. However, someone pointed out that Mirabel touches the candle and then wipes her hands on her shirt. A few have speculated this is why she didn't get her gift.
Personally, I think her gift is to become the next Abuela and that connecting/understanding her family was part of that gift. It's possible too that she has a lot more control of the house than others do.  We don't see many other people understanding Casita or talking to Casita as much as Mirabel and Abuela.  That's why I think she will be the next head of the family and she had to create a new candle with Abuela in order to take over.

Comment: The wiping hand theory debunked by the director; https://mobile.twitter.com/thejaredbush/status/1484929863815290882?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1484929863815290882%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fencanto-movie-mirabel-gift-sabotage-theory-debunked-director%2F

Comment: Mirabel being destined to inherit Abuela’s position as caretaker is exactly how I saw it, since after all Abuela did not have a specific gift outside of her stewardship of the house and Mirabel demonstrated a closer connection to Casita than anyone.

Answer (score 6):

In line with [Chan Dee's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262159/46407), Mirabel was chosen as the one to show that life was not about the gifts. The gifts are not what made you special, and that is what everyone was focusing on - all too much. The message in the movie is that life was about family. You have to pay attention to your family and care for them, regardless of your own desires.

As for why Mirabel was the one that was chosen, there's probably lots of reasons why she didn't receive a gift, but I believe (as is usually the case with Disney movies) that The Magic<sup>TM</sup> always knows what it's doing, so it chose Mirabel on purpose. The Magic<sup>TM</sup> had seen what was happening to the family, and it chose Mirabel as a means to fix it all.

Answer (score 3):

According to Jared Bush, [it's intentionally ambiguous](https://www.polygon.com/2021/11/27/22799299/encanto-ending-mirabel-magic) as to why she didn't receive a gift, and she still does not have a gift at the end of the film.

(bolding mine)

> By the end of the movie, Mirabel and the rest of the Madrigals are finally able to understand each other. They learn to see each other as people, beyond their special gifts and prescribed family roles. But while the Madrigals are able to embrace their imperfections, **Mirabel never does get any powers**. In fact, the film never reveals exactly why she didn’t get powers in the first place. **Bush says that isn’t what the story is meant to be about**.
>
> “I think there are so many reasons that people can relate to Mirabel about feeling left out and lesser-than,” he tells Polygon. “Rather than put some magical reason why, I think it’s clear in the film that she is who she needs to be for a very good reason.”
>
> Bush explains that from the moment the movie was conceptualized, the filmmakers knew Mirabel would be the main character. In a family full of magic users, she immediately became the perfect vehicle for the story, and more importantly, a sympathetic character for the audience.
>
> “This one young woman just was not given the same opportunity as the rest of these extraordinary people,” explains Bush. “The empathy was just there for her from the beginning [..] **I love that the reason [she lacks powers] isn’t exactly stated.**”